# Change Safari search suggestions language on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, search

The search suggestions in Safari always suggest results in Dutch to me, despite using my phone in English, and my Google set to English by default.

I am Dutch and live in the Netherlands, so I guess this is intended behaviour, but I find the Dutch wikipedia pages to be lacking quite often, for example.

Is there any way to change this language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the Non-World Wide Web !

In the good old days, search engines respected the principles of the World Wide Web. Then they started to alter their outputs according to *guessed language* and *guessed location*.

Your problem comes from the search engine used by Safari : Google or Bing or another one.

You may try these possible solutions :

1. Go to the Web site of the search engine, and look into its prefs.
2. Write to the search engine’s editor. And be patient.
3. Switch Safari to another search engine.
4. Use a proxy to disguise your location. I don’t recommend this workaround, it is dirty, we shouldn’t have to do this.